# Will Earth be devastated when the orbit shifts 1 metre towards the Sun?

Tags: gravity, cosmology, astrophysics, astronomy

There are some arguments in my country from a population that they are "religious". Then, their argument is that there is a perfect balance in universe and solar system.

Hence they say that Earth will collapse when the orbit of Earth shifts 1 meter towards the Sun. Is there a something like this?

What is the mechanism of orbiting, just laws of curvature of space or Newton's gravity laws? Or do you believe that universe is perfectly "designed" and everything in universe is in a perfect balance?

It seems to be a philosophic question but I think that we can understand this only and only by physics and astronomy.

Comment: The Earth's orbit is an ellipse, and over the course of a year its (centre to centre) distance to the Sun varies from 147,098,074 km to 152,097,701 km.

Comment: Venus and Mercury are closer to the sun than Earth is.  Have they "collapsed"?

Comment: @WillO if Earth were moved 50 or 100 million kilometers closer to the Sun it would certainly collapse in the sense intended in the question.

Comment: @my2cts:  That would depend on the details of how it's moved.  (I took "collapse" to mean "fall into the sun".  Maybe you took it otherwise, but I guess neither of us can really know the original intent.)

Comment: Thank you all guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance between Earth and sun is not constant as the Earth moves in an elliptic orbital around the sun. Its distance varies by 5 million kilometers between early January and early July. So on average its distance to the sun changes by 1 meter every 3  seconds. The maximum radial speed us about 1 meter per second. Of this answer may not satisfy some people, but you can try.

Comment: This seems to me to be non-responsive to (my reading of) the question, which I took to posit a shift of the entire orbit, making it, on average, one meter closer to the sun than it is now.  Of course it's not entirely clear which of our readings is closer to the OP's intent.

Comment: The is a 5 billion meter systematic variation. This means that a 1 meter shift of the average cannot be significant, let alone destroy the planet. I thought this is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting is that according to Newton's Laws, the Earth orbits the Sun in an elliptical orbit. If you perturb such an orbit a little, it will remain an elliptical orbit, albeit with slightly different eccentricity. So no: the Earth will not be "devastated" in the sense that it falls into the Sun.

A different orbit will, however, lead to a different amount of solar radiation reaching the Earth. Whether that kills life on Earth is a separate question that has as much to do with biology as with physics. I don't know the answer to that, although I'd be surprised if a perturbation of only 1 meter can devastate life on Earth (keep in mind the Earth's distance from the Sun already varies by more than 1 meter throughout the year).